# scan_parquet_files blocking async main thread in Rust Polars

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I am trying to read multiple parquet files using scan_parquet_files in azure. Most of the times below codes works fine but then 5% or 10% of times the code gives below error:

*thread 'main' panicked at 'Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. This happens because a function (like `block_on`) attempted to block the current thread while the thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.', /home/xyx/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-0.2.21/src/runtime/enter.rs:38:5*
*note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.*

Basically Polars thread blocking the tokio main thread(async) and need to use spawn blocking, but not sure why spawn_blocking doesn't work 100% of the times. Is there any better way to achieve this, which doesn't give the above mentioned error?

Here is the code:

```
//Function for reading files from cloud
fn fetch_data (store: Vec<&str>,mpath:&str,args:ScanArgsParquet)->                          Result<LazyFrame,PolarsError> {

let mut paths:Vec<PathBuf> = Vec::new();
for &s in store.iter(){
    let p = format!("{}{}{}{}","azure:/",mpath,&s,".parquet");
  
    let p1 = PathBuf::from(p);
    paths.push(p1);
}
let df = LazyFrame::scan_parquet_files(paths.into(),args).unwrap().with_streaming(true);

match df {
    a => return Ok(a),
    _  => return Err(PolarsError::NoData("Not data found".into()))
};

}

#\[tokio::main\]
async fn main() -\> PolarsResult\<()\>{
//Provide Blob Storage Name and Key
let AccountName = std::env::var("STORAGE_ACC_NAME").expect("missing STORAGE_ACCOUNT");
let AccountKey =  std::env::var("access_key").expect("missing STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY");
let AccountKey =  std::env::var("container_name").expect("missing STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY");

const TEST_S2: &str = "https://cprxt.blob.core.windows.net/blob_1";

//set up cloud options    
let cloud_options=cloud::CloudOptions::default().with_azure([(Key::AccountName,AccountName),(Key::AccessKey,AccountKey),(Key::ContainerName,ContName),(Key::Endpoint,TEST_S2)]);
let mut args = ScanArgsParquet::default();

//Set Options for scan parquet 
args.row_count=None;
args.n_rows = None;
args.low_memory=false; 
args.use_statistics = false;
args.cache= false;
args.parallel = ParallelStrategy::RowGroups;
args.cloud_options = Some(cloud_options);



                //Define Master Paths 
                let mpath_fp = "/read_parquet/fp_data/";
                let mpath_product = "/read_parquet/product_data/";   
                let mpath_sales = "/read_parquet/sales/";    
                let mpath_attribute_product = "/read_parquet/attribute_product/";
                let mpath_vars = "/read_parquet/vars/";
                
                //Parquet Partitions for all the files
                let mut input1 = vec!["1 ------- 33","4 ------- 33", "6 ------- 33", "7 ------- 33", "10 ------- 33"]; 
                
                
                //////New function for parquet retrieval # Using scan parquet inside spawn_blocking to avoid blocking the main thread by polars
                let dfs= tokio::task::spawn_blocking( move || {
                    let fp = fetch_data(input1.clone(),mpath_fp,args.clone()).unwrap();
                    let df_product = fetch_data(input1.clone(),mpath_product,args.clone()).unwrap();
                    let df_sales = fetch_data(input1.clone(),mpath_sales,args.clone()).unwrap();
                    let mut df_vars = fetch_data(input1.clone(),mpath_vars,args.clone()).unwrap();
                   
                    let dp=    collect_all(vec![fp,df_product,df_sales,df_vars]).unwrap();
                
                
                    (dp)
                
                }).await.expect("Task panicked");
                
                
                Ok(())
                
                
                }
```